# Deploying actions on google webhook on glitch

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to deploy [this](https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action) example on [glitch](https://glitch.com). I've added package.js and index.js to my glitch project and built successfully.

However, the code is missing a section to listen for HTTPS requests. In most node.js/express webapps, there is code to indicate which paths trigger which functions, but this is missing from the example. Can you explain to me how it should work and why that part is missing from this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what do you mean by "the code is missing a section to listen" as the only main feature of index.js is to listen to requests and return information.

I suggest you check [index.js](https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action/blob/master/index.js) and make sure that you getting requests to your end point on glitch.

Also, it would be helpful if you can share your glitch project over here at SO so we could see what you are doing.
Btw, you might want to double check that you have all the [packages](https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action/blob/master/package.json)

I also created this [simple example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aog-template) on Glitch - It's returning the current bitcoin price. Feel free to remix it and use the code there for your own action.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ido, thanks for your help! I'm going to use your example on glitch :). BTW, in the original code there is no express app handling the web hook. How that is supposed to work without it?

Comment: Firebase Functions essentially does the express setup, middleware, and routing configuration for you. You just pick up at the point it passes you a request and a response. If you're not using Firebase, you need to do all that work yourself, as Ido's glitch example shows.

Comment: If you wish to work without 'express' (or any other framework) I suggest you have another look at firebase functions. The code in the github repo is aimed for that type of deployment. However, the glitch example, is a great way to 'start quickly' but you do need the setup of 'express' in order to handle the routing.

Comment: Hi Ido, I would love to create bots with Firebase functions, however I'm very concerned about the costs involved. If I enable billing and my bot gets viral, expenses will go out of control with no return for me. Is there a way to monetize on these bots?

Comment: Well, check here: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ I think that even in a case of a very successful bot you are still inside a 'free' plan. Plus, you can always limit the spending.

Answer (score 0):

The part that "listens to requests" is

```
// The Entry point to all our actions
  const actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(ACTION_PRICE, priceHandler);
  actionMap.set(ACTION_TOTAL, totalHandler);
  actionMap.set(ACTION_BLOCK, blockCountHandler);
  actionMap.set(ACTION_MARKET, marketCaptHandler);
  actionMap.set(ACTION_INTERVAL, intervalHandler);

  assistant.handleRequest(actionMap);
```

where each ACTION is an action(in an intent) in Dialogflow and the handler is the corresponding function in your code.

I'd recommend you take a look at

> https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/assistant-codelab/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

If you want a good example of an assistant app, though this uses firebase instead of glitch.

Comment: Hi Bart, the issue is that I don't want to use Google Functions on Firebase. I want to use glitch.com or any other free service. In my understanding this can be done by using an express handler listening to post requests, create an instance of the assistant, pull the information from external site and send back to the assistant.